# Serialization for Azure Redis Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, stackexchange.redis

I have an ASP.Net app hosted on Azure App Service.

I understood that the default "**InProc**" session caching doesn't work in Azure.

Was looking for workaround, and came across Redis, which I have enabled in Azure and set following in the config file

```
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="RedisStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
         host="xxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380" accessKey="xxx=" ssl="true"
         redisSerializerType="MyApp.Net.Helper.JsonSerializer,MyApp.Net"
         />
  </providers>
</sessionState></system.web>
```

By default, I started getting ***assembly not serialized*** error for some forms. Since I'm using EF with 50 tables, not sure which one was to be serialized and it becomes tedious.

Hence enabled a custom handler handler here :

```
    public class JsonSerializer : Microsoft.Web.Redis.ISerializer
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    Error = (serializer, err) => {
        err.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
    };

public byte[] Serialize(object data)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Settings));
    }

    public object Deserialize(byte[] data)
    {
        return data == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data), Settings);
    }
}
```

But this was like serializing every object there and I feel its actually slowing down the system further. And then it was failing on some object arrays, like [following](https://www.screencast.com/t/3YahfWhFeUP)

If I ignore the error like the code above (which I know is bad practice), sometimes I come across ***System.OutOfMemoryException*** exception.

Any advise appreciated here.

Comment: ``I started getting assembly not serialized error for some forms.`` Did you check which specific Type in which Assembly is not marked as serializable?

Comment: @FredHan-MSFT - yes, these are my data models . Like Product, Customer, and etc.

Comment: Still looking for an answer

Comment: @RandeepSingh , Did you find the resolution. i am facing something similar issue on Azure server

Comment: @RSB nope at that stage. We proceeded without using Redis. Can't recall what was the choice then.

Answer (score 0):

> I started getting assembly not serialized error for some forms

When the [Session State Provider for Redis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider) is used, we should make sure that the data types that are being stored in session state are serializable.

And as I know, the error message should indicates which type in which assembly is not marked as serializable, which should help us quickly find the specific type is not serializable from code behind.

> this was like serializing every object there and I feel its actually slowing down the system further. And then it was failing on some object arrays

You could find specific types/objects based on the error details `Type 'xxx' in Assembly 'xxx, Version=...' is not marked as serializable` that you see in web page and try to do serialization for only these types/objects. Besides, if possible, you could use [NonSerializedAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to some fields of the object.

Comment: Yes, the error defines the unmarked object, but its just tedious to run test script/debug to identify list of the objects.
I would rather that all objects are not serialized by default, and I choose what to serialized as per required.
Can't we just try the caching with DOM only first?